# mongoDB - cursor only updates 1 document using node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB (3.4) with a node.js driver and I'm trying to update a field in all documents contained within "items_collection". I've tried a couple of different approaches but I can't seem to find a solution which correctly updates ALL documents. Below is the code I've currently got:

```
var cursor = db.collection('items_collection').find();
cursor.on("end", function() {
    console.log("Finished. Closing db...");
    db.close();
}); 

cursor.on("err", function() {
    console.dir("Error on:" + err);
    throw err;
});

cursor.on("data", function(doc) {
    cursor.pause();

    var newTitle = getTitleFromDescription(doc.description);
    db.collection('items_collection').update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{title: newTitle}}, {multi:true});

    cursor.resume();
});
```

This seems reasonably sane to me, however it's only ever the first document which gets its title updated to "test_title". I must be missing something obvious here right?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The reason I didn't use the one line `update()` approach is that the title needs to be generated from a field within the document so I need access to the documents as I iterate through them in order to pull this out. I can't (to my knowledge) do that without using a more hands-on iteration approach such as a cursor.


I oversimplified and dropped out the dynamic title generation from my original post - my bad!. I've added it back to illustrate what I mean...

Comment: Okay. I've edited the code again and swapped out the `save()` for `update()` and I've made use of `$set` and `multi:true`. However, I'm still only seeing the first document get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **update** instead of **save** and use `multi : true` for multiple document udpates:

```
db.collectionname.update( {}, { $set:{ title : "newvalue" } }, { multi : true } );
```

All updates in MongoDB are, by default, singular. you must add a `multi : true`

```
cursor.on("data", function(doc) {
    cursor.pause();

    var newTitle = getTitleFromDescription(doc.description);

    console.log(doc._id);
    console.log(newTitle);

    db.collection('items_collection').update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{title: newTitle}}, {multi:true}).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);  
        console.log('++++++++++++++++++');
        cursor.resume();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried this within the cursor and I'm still only seeing the first document get updated. I also can't use this outside of a cursor as it doesn't provide access to self (the document I'm updating) which is needed when generating a new title.

Comment: in your updated question you are providing the {_id: doc._id}. this is like where  clause and its pointing to only one document you have to keep first object empty {} if you want to update every single document

Comment: its seems that you dont want the bulk update. every document must be updated with the title fetched from its desription right ? if yes then console.log(doc._id) after cursor.pause(); and check how many times it prints and its different every time or same

Comment: I looked at `updateMany()` which makes bulk updating super-simple but you can't access self so I think the bulk update approach isn't an option. If I add a log straight after `cursor.pause();` I get all the document IDs log out (all different) as expected.

Comment: this is strange. if document id is changing at every iteration and update is called each time then it should update each Document. One thing you can try is let me update my anwer

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much! That seems to work :) I guess the cursor wasn't pausing for long enough resulting in the strange 1 document update only behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a multi-update.  Assuming you want to update every document in your collection, you would do:

```
db.collection("items_collection").update({},{$set:{title: "test_title"},{multi:true} );
```

The docs explain this clearly [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-multi).

Also note that you must update operator expressions for multi-updates. If you were updating a single document, the second parameter to the `update` method can be a plain object of `field:value`, but a multi-update has to use an [update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) like `$set` in the example above.

Comment: As mentioned in my response to Asif, I still only get the first document update using this approach. I've updated the code snippet above to reflect what I've got.